# Transferring a String from an ActionEvent

Tags: java

First of all, sorry but I don't know how to reduce my code to a small yet understandable example, so I'll have to explain what I want.

I'm using the standard [MCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model for a large class.

```
public FruitShop() {
    model();
    view();
    controller();
}
```

A ComboBox is created in view(); the ArrayList populating it is created in model() and gets modified in controller().

I need to transfer the currently selected element of that ComboBox for another class to use. To get a proper result, it seems that I can only use the following command in ActionEvent method (@Override) or in controller().

```
String fDelete = (String) fruitList.getSelectedItem();
```

It would be cleanest if I could either transfer it from the ActionEvent or make it global for the class somehow and then transfer it to the other class. I assume it would be ok to work on it in controller(), but I feel I'd have a fun time trying to pass it to the ActionEvent then.

Please assume that I am completely hopeless in this case and vague hints won't help. I have spent over a day overall on this question, had to take a bad alternative way(recreating the ComboBox in the other class) but I still want to do it nicely and understand the concepts behind it. Yet, I don't have the time to research it more, so I ask for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over complicating the issue.

The view class should handle the view. So it should figure out what's in the combobox, and tell the controller what to do. What exactly the method should be in the controller depends on the context, but I would expect something along the lines of the following:

1. Action Listener calls action
2. Action querys the combobox for the fruit type. They're in the same class, so it can just ask the combobox for its selected item. Probably returns an enum. You could also use Strings, but that's not best practice.
3. Action calls `controller.deleteFruit(FruitTypeEnum fruitType);`

Comment: First of all, it is a bit unclear to me what you're doing in Step 3. The way it looks, you put the fDelete into the controller() and try to pass it to the ActionEvent. I've just tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Also, the change to use an "enum" was pretty confusing, and I'd love to apply minimum changes to ensure I do it right. Finally, I'm still not sure how to pass the value to another class if needed. Thanks for trying to help, but I need a more details to deal with this.